# Best strategy to backup btrfs root filesystem?

Tags: backup, btrfs, snapshot

I have a btrfs root partition with an `@` root subvolume and an `@home` subvolume and I do auto-snapshots during updates and timeshift scheduled snapshots, both of which are saved on the same drive. This is great but I want to have extra redundancy in case of a drive failure.

In my last setup on Debian, I used the ext4 filesystem and put my timeshift rsync backups on an external drive.

How can I do something similar, i.e. backup to an external drive, while still taking snapshots on the root device?

In addition to the system device, which is a 1TB SSD formated as btrfs, I have a 2 TB HDD currently formatted with two NTFS paritions since I dual boot windows as well. Now I would be willing to completely move to a linux filesystem on that drive but I don't know how I would handle backing up the root drive. I thought about doing a disk image onto the HDD with `dd`  but if I do this, I would (a) loose an extra TB of storage if I understand correctly how `dd` works and (b) would not now how to restore from the image. Ideally, I would like to have a btrfs partition on the second drive for backups of the root device only and a second (e.g. ext4 or ntfs) partition just for overflow data storage.

Essentially my question is: How can I facilitate a backup of my already "snapshotting" root partition (and also know how to restore from it)?

**EDIT: My solution**

The solution I came up with uses [`btrbk`](https://github.com/digint/btrbk), which is a single perl script that manages snapshots and automatically sends them to another drive. I documented the setup on my github account [here](https://github.com/weygoldt/dotfiles/tree/master/system/backup-arch).

`btrbk` runs using a single config file to specify snapshot and backup locations as well as retention policies. I schedule the backup process using crontab. It is a little work to set it up for beginners but much more rewarding in the learning process than simply using snapper or timeshift.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/back_up_btrfs_snapshots_external_drives/

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I come up with for this kind of requirement: https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync

I prepared my own scripts to backup to a target: https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync-new-target

Here is the overall backup system I'm using: https://github.com/ceremcem/erik-sync

This process is quite a bit complex and requires a deep knowledge. In short, [this script](https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync-new-target/blob/a450d25a5b535d7e953e15eae995bdbb126983ef/auto.sh) does the followings:

- Defer any automatic suspend actions in order not to interrupt the backup process.
- Send all snapshots to the target.
- Create a new rootfs within the target by using the latest snapshots.
- Modify necessary files such as $target/rootfs/etc/fstab, .../etc/crypttab, etc. accordingly.
- Mount the boot partition, copy the most recent boot files into it.
- Update GRUB bootloader in a `chroot` environment.

Now our target disk (backup disk) is the exact copy of our current system, without using `dd` command. You can create any additional partitions in the target disk according to your needs, this will not break this backup process.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This setup is probably overkill for my needs so I used [btrbk](https://github.com/digint/btrbk), which just sends the snapshots to a second drive. As far as I understand, this is only useful in cases of software errors, right? In case of a hardware error, could I install the snapshots on a new drive?